# OSPF with multi-areas

Tags: cisco, routing, router, ospf, packet-tracer

I'm trying to recreate a theoretical situation in packet tracer with 3 areas with the protocol OSPF for some reason there's no communication between the devices, even when the ospf hop can see the other devices.

**R1**

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 1.1.1.1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 area 1
 network 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.3 area 1
!
```

**R2**

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 11.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 10.0.0.2 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 2.2.2.2
 log-adjacency-changes
 area 2 virtual-link 3.3.3.3
 network 10.0.0.0 0.0.0.3 area 1
 network 11.0.0.0 0.0.0.3 area 2
!
```

**R3**

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 11.0.0.2 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 12.0.0.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 3.3.3.3
 log-adjacency-changes
 area 2 virtual-link 2.2.2.2
 network 11.0.0.0 0.0.0.255 area 2
 network 12.0.0.0 0.0.0.3 area 3
!
```

**R4**

```
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 192.168.1.1 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface FastEthernet0/1
 ip address 12.0.0.2 255.255.255.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
!
interface Vlan1
 no ip address
 shutdown
!
router ospf 1
 router-id 4.4.4.4
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 12.0.0.0 0.0.0.3 area 3
 network 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 area 3
!
```

[image: Network]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Areas 1 and 3 can't directly communicate with Area 2. OSPF areas can only connect to to Area 0. If you change Area 2 to Area 0, things should work much better. Also, you can't have discontiguous Area 0s.

Comment: i'm not sure of following you, are you saying i always need a area 0, and go from there?

Comment: A single area OSPF network doesn't need to be Area 0, but muli-area OSPF networks require an Area 0, and all other areas can only communicate with Area 0. This is OSPF 101. It helps OSPF maintain a loop-free topology.

Comment: I changed the areas to: Area 0 -> Area 1 -> Area 2 in a tutorial on youtube worked for him, but for me nothing, how can be? His network didn't work either until he applied the virtual-link comand to the area 1 to both routers.

Comment: Area 2, in your drawing, needs to be Area 0. The two routers in that area need to have the interfaces to each other in Area 0, and the other interfaces in the respective area to which they are connecting. This site isn't for discussions like this. I have answered your question, and if you have other specific questions, you need to post a different question. There is also the chat room for back and forth Q&A.

Comment: Ok it's working now, the problem was with some config, i used the Area 0 > Area 1(virtual linked) > Area 2, thank you!

Comment: I know you configured the virtual link for lab purposes, which is a great idea, but I just thought I'd let you know (in case you didn't know already) it is best to avoid them in production networks. Also, just in case you're interested, I have written a handful of "OSPF LSA Deep Dive" blog posts - http://www.oznetnerd.com/2015/04/21/a-deep-dive-in-ospf-lsas-index/ - though they might be a bit overkill if you're not looking into the details of OSPF's workings at this stage.